# Unable to scroll to sides in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, asp-classic, vbscript

I have created website in ASP classic and i'm unable to scroll to sides in chrome (-> and -<)

Do I need to change any pluging/code in the sites?

Please help

Thanks!

Comment: Left side or Right side scroll work when your document size is more then browser screen view size. Are you sure that width is more then browser size and you view them in 100 % zoom.

Comment: You expect someone to debug this without posting source code, or at least a link to the web page? I can't see your screen from where I'm sitting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No horizontal scrolling in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704375/no-horizontal-scrolling-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the chrome. Hope it will be fixed soon (usually it is).

Try to update your browswer.